# Permissions to see content

Tags: permissions, directory

If the owner/group of a folder and/or is set to 0 0 (zero zero), can I see its content? I'm trying to access a directory with such permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner/group being set to 0 0 implies it's owner and group is root.  Whether you can see inside it depends on the permissions of the last 3 letters of the permissions string.

Type: `ls -ld <dirname>.`
You should see something like:
drwxr-x**r-x** 32 root root 4096 Jul 19 2013 <dirname>

If the last character is - (not x) then you have no access to that directory at all. Otherwise, if "r" is also set, then you can list the contents of the directory (and "w" allows you to create items in there).

Comment: by the way , it is not uncommon for a regular user to join the root group .